# How long does thread live in server-client in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client-server

I have this simple server-client example:

`FooServer.java`:

```
public class FooServer {
    private Socket clientSocket;

    public class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
        private BufferedReader reader;
        private PrintWriter writer;

        public ClientHandler(Socket socket) {
            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            String message;
            System.out.println("start of server run()");
            try {
                writer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                while ((message = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("inside of server loop - get new message");
                    writer.println(message);
                    writer.flush();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("end of server run()");
        }
    }

    public void go() {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5000);
            while (true) {
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                Thread watchIncome = new Thread(new ClientHandler(clientSocket));
                watchIncome.start();
                System.out.println("got connection");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FooServer().go();
    }
}
```

and `FooClient.java`:

```
public class FooClient {
    private BufferedReader reader;
    private PrintWriter writer;
    private Socket socket;

    public class ReadIncome implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("start of client run()");
            String mes;
            try {
                while ((mes = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("inside of client loop");
                    System.out.println(mes);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("end of client run()");
        }
    }

    public void go(String writeOut) {
        try {
            socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5000);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //--------HERE-----------
        //how long will this thread live?
        Thread readerThread = new Thread(new ReadIncome());
        readerThread.start();
        writer.println(writeOut);
        writer.flush();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FooClient foo = new FooClient();
        foo.go("dummy text");
    }
}
```

I run FooServer.java, which in turn spawn new `watchIncome` (thread that is looking for messages from client as `while ((message = reader.readLine()) != null)`). But in server, it does so in `while(true)` infinite loop, so it *incessantly* spawns new threads looking for incoming messages.

However, in client, there is no such infinite loop. As far as I know about threads in Java, a thread runs the `run()` method and... It's done. The thread is dead (i.e. cannot be "reset" to run again). And since the client does *not* spawns new threads (there is no infinite loop unlike in server), the client should not be "waiting" for respond from server, since the thread should be already dead (that's how I understand the threads in java - just run the `run()` method **once**).

But instead, the client will hang in middle of the `run()` method -> it will print just `inside of client loop`, and will never finish. But how's that possible, since the thread should be dead? Once `readerThread.start();`, and inside the method, this statement `while ((mes = reader.readLine()) != null)` will evaluate to false (the string has nothing, and thus is null), and the method finish, there should be no waiting for server response (because I suppose the thread is started immediately).

And moreover - even if the statement does evaluate to true (say, the server was launched first, so the client gets the response as early as it launches), the client will - again, hang up in inside of client loop, in the middle of `run()`, but it shouldn't, as there is no loop so it should continue to the end of the method (and thus to the end of the thread). At the end, I have to terminate the process of server (that makes sense, since I never close the server socket), but with that, the client process will end as well. But it should be already dead. Can someone please explain, why is client "waiting", but it should not?

Comment: The client (as well as the server) is _blocked_. The documentation for [`BufferedReader.readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) does not mention that explicitly, but it says "or null **if the end of the stream has been reached** without reading any characters". However, neither the client nor the server is closing the streams or the connection (resulting in an "end of stream"); therefore both will wait indefinitely for a message from the other party.

Comment: @Marcono1234 but if the server is *blocked* as you say, then why is it possible for it to accept new clients that will connect to it? That is, when the first client connect, then (as expected), the server prints `inside of server loop`, which is expected. But then another client to connection will cause the server `inside of server loop`. So when the thread with the loop will first run and block for the first client, it should not (becuase it is blocked) serve the other connection (it is still the same thread, the same **blocked** thread).

Comment: @Marcono1234 so if there are IO stream blocking (as per documentation you mentioned), then *multiple*-connection to server should not be possible, unless the server thread will get unblocked. In other words,  **when** will get thread *unblocked*? Is that, the server gets even *unblocked*? And then it servers another client connection?

Comment: My comment was slightly inaccurate; it is not the `FooServer` which is blocked, but the new threads it creates, which then execute `ClientHandler` (which is the one calling `readLine()`). That is the reason why your server is still able to accept new requests, but the handlers for each request will be blocked.